# upgrade git on Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx)

Tags: apt, git

I currently have Git 1.7.1.0 installed but need to upgrade to 1.7.1.1 (at least). I tried running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and also tried

```
sudo apt-get install git-core
```

but each time I get a message indicating that there is no later version of git available. I have the following software sources configured in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://ubunturepo.de.bonial.lan lucid main restricted multiverse universe
deb http://ubunturepo.de.bonial.lan lucid-security main restricted multiverse universe
deb http://ubunturepo.de.bonial.lan lucid-updates main restricted multiverse universe
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu lucid main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu lucid main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid multiverse universe
```

Comment: what do I need to run on the command-line to add this?

Comment: made it an answer. If this does not work please edit it into your question and Ill delete it.

Answer (score 34):

To install the [latest stable](https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=lucid) from command line...

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

This should let you install `1.8.2-1~ppa0~lucid2`.

Comment: Is it essential to install `python-software-properties` ?

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana: Yes, if you don't already have `add-apt-repository`

Answer (score 0):

Please open the terminal using this shortcut

ctrl+alt+T

Then type these commands on terminal

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install git